# C# Time Range Checking

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, time, timetable

I have a very hard problem. This program is about time tables for school. I want to find a  time in range in my database. I am using C# and MSSQL 2012. Below is my db schema.

http://upic.me/show/47164036

1. cr_id is classroom id.
2. tch_id is teacher_id.
3. std_gro is student group id.
4. start_time is a time that subject start.
5. end time is a time that subject is finish.
6. hour is a hour that subject take.
7. subj_id is subject id.
8. day_set is a number of the day (ex 1=monday).

I want to check for duplicates across subject, teacher, cr and student, but how can I check it?

I have tried:

Step 1:

```
select * from Action_Classroom where ((start_time <= 9) and (end_time > 9)) and dat_set = 2
```

Step 2:

```
select * from Action_Classroom where (end_time between 9 and 9+x) and dat_set = 2 ;
```

In a loop I send the value of hour as x.

but I cannot figure out how to check for duplicate time.

If anyone have some example for me please tell me, thank you so much.

Comment: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Comment: Also, I have no clue what this means: `I want to check dupicate,cross over for subject , teacher, cr and student how can I check it?`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from Action_Classroom as a join Action_Classroom as b
on a.cr_id = b.cr_id
and a.tch_id= b.tch_id
and a.day_set = b.day_set
and a.subj_id= b.subj_id
and a.start_time <= b.end_time
and b.start_time <= a.end_time
```